# Get month after and before given month name

Tags: php, date, strtotime

How do I get the month name after a given month. So for June, I would want July

I have tried:

```
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('June', "next month"));
```

This display January, which is obviously wrong, I am looking for July.

How would I then get the month before?

I have tried

```
$prev_month = date('F',strtotime('June - 1 month'));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('June + 1 month'));
```

or

```
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('June next month'));
```

**edit**

```
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('June last month'));
```

Comment: how about previous month ?

Comment: `echo date('F',strtotime('June ' . date('Y') . ' -1 month'));` - You need to include the year for previous month.  [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5489502/138383)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('F',strtotime('June + 1 month'));
```