# How to get Next_month name in php

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code

```
$customer->where(DATE_FORMAT(month,'%m')=date('m',strtotime('+1 month')));
```

how to get next month name ,i have try it. but i got the error this
Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Please do some research before asking question. If you have searched google you would have got this first link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514291/get-month-after-and-before-given-month-name

Answer (score 3):

Just do this, You can get the next month from here and use it in where you want.

[Online Test](https://3v4l.org/7dgsP)

```
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('next month')); // June
```

If you know the name of the last month then use-

```
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('June next month')); // July
```

Comment: actually my question is i have selected 5 month , i need display next month name

Comment: $customer = DB::table('customer');
  $customer->join('customer_month_calender','customer_month_calender.customer_id','=','customer.id','left');
  $customer->select('customer.id','customer_month_calender.month');
  $customer->where(DATE_FORMAT(month,'%m')=date('m',strtotime('+1 month')));
  $customer->orderBy('customer_month_calender.month', 'asc');
  $customer->groupBy('customer.id');
  return $customer->get();

Comment: so you need to know the 5th month and name it before the `next`. like: `strtotime('may next month')`