# How to get YEAR of previous month using date()

Tags: php

I want to get the year of the previous month.

For example in `July 2012` I want result `2012`. 
But in `January 2013` I want result `2012` 
and in `Feb 2013` I want result `2013`

I have searched and found this [How to get previous month and year relative to today, using strtotime and date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489502)
It uses `date_create` function (i.e. DateTime Class). But I want a solution without using it. i.e. by using simple `date()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Should work as expected.