# PHP strtotime: Get previous month

Tags: php, date, strtotime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get previous month and year relative to today, using strtotime and date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489502/how-to-get-previous-month-and-year-relative-to-today-using-strtotime-and-date)

Today is December, 31st but `strtotime("-1 months")` returns December:

```
echo date("Y-m", strtotime("-1 months"));
```

Same for `strtotime("last month")`

How can I properly return the previous month (November)?

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XvMaMB

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
strtotime("first day of last month")
```

The `first day of` is the important part as detailed on the [Relative Formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative) manual page.

---

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dB35q8 (with hard-coded today's date)

Comment: Thanks. Very misleading! Sounds like it would return "1" or the weekday.

Comment: @Martin Try it and find out

Comment: @Martin: `strtotime` always returns a timestamp (or false on failure). So it *will* return a timestamp of the first day of the last month, but since you are outputting it in `Y-m` format, that's fine for you.

Comment: "first day of next month" doesn't work in PHP 5.2.4

Comment: Lots of things won't work in ancient versions of the language.

Comment: What will happen if the date is something like 2014-01-31 will it return 2013-12-01..?

Answer (score 11):

`strtotime("-1 months")` would be `2012-11-31`, but there's no November, 31st. It is one day past `2012-11-30`, which gives `2012-12-01`. You will see it, when you do

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 months"));
```

gives as output

> 2012-12-01

See [codepad](http://codepad.org/PxA63tYN)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.