# get last 3 months from current month using php

Tags: php

I want to get last 3 months name from current month. For example current month is August. So, I want the datas like these June, July, August. I have tried this code `echo date("F", strtotime("-3 months"));` . it returns June only. How do I get last 3 months from current month using php?

Comment: Could you just create a `for` loop and decrement the subtraction each time adding the result to an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually on the right track by using date and strtotime functions. Expanding it below to your requirements:

```
function getMonthStr($offset)
{
    return date("F", strtotime("$offset months"));
}

$months = array_map('getMonthStr', range(-3,-1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple code:

```
<?php

for($x=2; $x>=0;$x--){
echo date('F', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -" . $x . " month"));
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Got the idea from LTroubs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489502/how-to-get-previous-month-and-year-relative-to-today-using-strtotime-and-date).

Answer (score 3):

That should work:

```
function lastThreeMonths() {
    return array(
        date('F', time()),
        date('F', strtotime('-1 month')),
        date('F', strtotime('-2 month'))
    );
}

var_dump(lastThreeMonths());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$current_date = date('F');
for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
{
    ${"prev_mont" . $i} = date('F',strtotime("-$i Months"));
    echo ${"prev_mont" . $i}."</br>";
}
echo $current_date."</br>";
```