# How to get first day of last month?

Tags: php, date

I need to get the first day of last name everyday.
I used to code it like this:

```
echo date('Ym01',strtotime('last month'));
```

But today (March 30,2017), it returned the first day of this month, not last month.

I tried `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last month'));` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489502/how-to-get-previous-month-and-year-relative-to-today-using-strtotime-and-date) but it returned `1970-01-01` instead.

Can someone explain to me why the code return date like that?

Comment: My output was, `2017-02-01`, as is expected? CentOS7 w/ PHP5.4.16. Is your system time set correctly?

Comment: one thing to remember about dates if it return 1970-01-01 then there is either no date or your format is messed up

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried in my local using xampp and it returned the date correctly. Looks like the problem is on the server. Could it be the server system's time not set correctly?
But if I only using date('Ymd') or date('Ymd',strtotime('yesterday')) it returned the correct date, today and yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

this must work even on older versions of php

```
<?php

$lastmonth= new datetime();
//formating the date
$lastmonth=$lastmonth->format("Ym01");
//subtracting 1 month to make it last month
$lastmonth=date('Ym01',strtotime($lastmonth . '-1 month'));
echo $lastmonth;

?>
```

If it doesn't work then the problem is with your server

Comment: there is a space in `new date time()`. Should be `new datetime();`.

Comment: I think there's a new typo   `newdate` can't be together.