# PHP - How to get value of previous month?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get previous month of current month. 
 For example, current month is October , the value return should be September.

I've tried

```
$currmonth = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

But it return the same month - October. But when I replace to `-2month`, it will return August which is correct.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489502/how-to-get-previous-month-and-year-relative-to-today-using-strtotime-and-date) is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$currmonth = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') - 1, 1, date('Y')));
```

**Output :**

```
September
```

Comment: I dont think the wants the name of the month instead of the month. 
Do you see the `m` in his posting?

Comment: this method is not working, i think is caused by my PHP version is too low

Answer (score 0):

```
$dt = new DateTime('first day of last month');
echo $dt->format('m');
// 09
```

Comment: this method is not working, i think is caused by my PHP version is too low